# Why a full stop, "." and not a plus symbol, "+", for string concatenation in PHP?

Tags: php, perl, syntax, operators, concatenation

Why did the designers of PHP decide to use a full stop / period / "." as the string
concatenation operator rather than the more usual plus symbol "+" ?

Is there any advantage to it, or any reason at all?  Or did they just like to? :o)

Comment: Due to the plethora of excellent answers given, I'd like to generalize  this question to include Perl.  i.e. why did the creators of Perl (and later PHP) chose to use a '.' over a '+'

Thanks!

Comment: I think a better question would be why Perl specifically chose `.` - the reasons why they wanted a distinct concatenation operator are clear enough (many languages do the same), but the choice of `.` of all things for this purpose seems to be a mystery.

Comment: There's nothing inherently concatenation-y about & or ~ or .. or . or + or any other symbol on my keyboard.  As a former mathematician and C programmer, + means either "a commutative, associative binary operation with an identity" or "pointer arithmetic" -- neither of which is anything like string concatenation.  I don't like PHP, but I can't find fault with their use of a different symbol to mean a different thing.  The symbol we use in proofreading to mean "smash these words together" would have been cooler, but nobody can type it.

Comment: The answer I gave below answers it independent of the language (its so that string concatenation is not confused with addition when both parameters are numbers).  So its a way of solving this problem for any language that supports automatic coercion of numbers to strings.

Comment: @Ken, what's the name of that symbol (for reference)?

Comment: CJ, just noticed your comment -- I think you should edit that into the question

Comment: @Pavel Minaev The mark (or symbol) for proofreading concatenation is called undertie, and it's drawn as an arc below the words or characters to be connected: /under‿tie/ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tie_(typography)

Comment: By the way, APL has always had some crazy looking characters as operators. The ravel or concatenation/lamination operator that can be used for string concetenation seems to be a comma (,) as in:
'Hello', ' ', 5⍴'World!' Try it out: http://tryapl.org/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The most obvious reason would probably be that PHP inherits a lot of its syntax from Perl - and Perl uses  a dot (`.`) for string concatenation.**

But, we can delve deeper into it and figure out why this was implemented in Perl - the `+` operator is most commonly used for mathematical equations  - it's only used for concatenation in languages in which the variable type can define the way in which the operator works (simple explanation, example is C#)

```
var intAddition = 1 + 2;
Console.WriteLine(intAddition); // Prints 3
var stringConcat = "1" + "2";
Console.WriteLine(stringConcat); // Prints "12"
```

^ As you can see, the `+` operator is used both for concatenation and addition in C#.

---

Perhaps the reasoning goes lower level and is due to the boolean algebra of [logic gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate) - `+` means `OR` in logic gates, whereas `.` is used as the `AND` operator - which makes sense when it comes to string concatenation.

It makes sense to have two separate operators, one for concatenation and one for addition - it's just unfortunate that these two can be mixed up due to other languages.

Comment: Hi, i am guessing one more reason but i don't know whether it is correct or not. The one more reason might be we are not specifying datatype for the variable right, without knowing string or int it can't concatenate, so they might have avoided this. of course var datatype is there but even i guess this. What you say? @Daniel May

Answer (score 35):

PHP's syntax is influenced by Perl, and `.` is the string concatenation operator in Perl.

In a weakly typed language there are advantages to having a different string concatenation and numeric addition operators: which one you use will influence which type the language coerces the variables to.

As it happens, Perl 6 will use a tilde `~` instead of a dot `.` for string concatenation, because `.` will be used for object member access. So it seems the designers of Perl now think it was a bad choice.

Perhaps, in Perl and PHP's early, non-Object-Oriented days, it seemed like as good a choice as any. Maybe the designers of both languages never envisaged them becoming strong OO languages.

As for whether PHP will one day ditch its `->` member access syntax for `.`, who knows?

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question "why the use of a period". It just defers the answer.

Comment: joshcomley: that was a valid point, so I have elaborated. Initially I took the reference to "the designers of PHP" at face value

Comment: Actaully Perl 6 now uses the "~" for string concatentaion.

Comment: mpeters: Thanks, it seems I was behind on this news, I have edited accordingly.

Comment: The de facto standardization on "." as the method operator post dates the adoption of "." for concatenation in Perl which then influenced PHP. And perl initially had no object orientation.

It is precisely because everyone now expects "." to indicate methods on objects that Perl 6 has adopted new syntax (from a perl point of view) allowing "." to be used for methods and using "~" for concatenation.

Comment: It's not so much that they thought it was a bad choice, as it was that the . operator has become the defacto method accessor in almost all languages.  Back then, it was a fine choice.  Now they want to use it for a different purpose.

Comment: Because if you used + for concatenation, like in Javascript, you run into typing issues due to loosely typed languages. The lexical parser has a hard time determining whether you want to do addition or concatenation.

Answer (score 20):

I am not a PHP expert, but, how else do you do differentiate that last two lines?

```
$first  = 100;
$second = 20;
$stringresult     = $first . $second; // "10020"
$arithmeticresult = $first + $second; // 120
```

Comment: For clarity - `$stringresult` returns "10020" and `$arithmeticresult` returns `120`.

Comment: You use some sane operator, like `&` which VB uses, or `~` which D (and, apparently, Perl6) uses, or `..` which Lua uses (which is IMO still weird, but still more understandable).

Comment: @Pavel: Well if you interpret the original poster's question as one of aesthetics then you may have a point -- I would prefer '&' myself as well, but I thought the technical explanation was what was really being asked for in this case (they thought using '+' for both cases was ok).

Comment: @Pavel: Why is `.` not a "sane operator" for concatenation? And just because you're used to using `.` for object members doesn't make it the most logical operator for that. (PHP's choice of `->` is quite good IMO.)

Comment: `->` isn't attrocious, but the most common use of that operator is in C++ as a shorthand to dereference pointers to objects or structs. Say there's a `struct` with a  member `x` and you have a pointer `p` to a struct of that type. Rather than using `(*p).x = 5;`, you would use `p->x = 5;`. Given PHP's C-like lineage, I think this overloads the syntax, even if there's no use for that operator in this context in PHP.

Comment: @Andrew - No. PHP inherits teh `->` syntax from Perl. In Perl, to dereference a hash reference, you use `my $hash = { this => "that" }; $hash->{this}`. It is conceptually performing a "dereference and then access", which is the same thing it does in C.

Answer (score 13):

Logically **+** is used for numbers. While a **dot** is used to concatenate two sentences (strings) in a paragraph for example. Hence dot is used to concatenate strings. So it is pretty logical i believe. It is better that way...

Comment: How often do you use string concatenation to concatenate sentences? Also, dot is a sentence _terminator_, not a sentence _separator_, so analogy breaks anyway.

Comment: Analogy is imperfect, film at 11.

Comment: Why do you put a dot in-between sentences? You should not include one i suppose :)

Answer (score 8):

[Douglas Crockford thinks that + for Concatenation is a Bad Idea](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html):

> JavaScript has its share of design errors, such as the overloading of + to mean both
>   addition and concatenation with type coercion

Comment: I agree with Doug. Once you get used to the syntax it's much clearer and less ambiguous - both worthwhile aims for syntax.

Comment: Yeah; Javascript + wrecks my brain on a regular basis, usually because it starts concatenating when I didn't want it to.

Comment: + for concatenation is one of the few things that regularly catches me out in JS

Answer (score 7):

The use of the dot as string concatenation operator in PHP probably dates back to Perl. Remember that PHP once was nothing more than a bunch of Perl scripts.

Also it makes sense to have distinct string concatenation and addition operators, especially in weakly-typed languages. There are enough pitfalls in PHP already to shoot yourself in the foot, you don't need to add another one.

Answer (score 5):

I would too prefer to use a full stop instead of a plus sign because I usually associate + with mathematical equations.

For Example `"this is a string " + 56 + 20`

This would be very confusing for both the compiler/interpreter and the developer.

However the disadvantage to using full stop for concatenation operator is that it is just a dot on the screen and sometimes you can't see whether is it in the string or outside the string.

Comment: Confusing if you are not used to it. In Java and C# this is the norm.

Comment: yeah i know. in Java i had to do this instead: `"this is a string " + (56 + 20)`

Comment: Being "used to it" has nothing to do with it.  I've been writing C# for a couple years, and before that Java since around 1999, and this ambiguous crap still confuses me.  (In comparison, Haskell's string concatenation operator took me about 10 seconds to figure out.)  Examples of crappy syntax are like assholes: every language has one and they all stink.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't answer the question, just wanted to share something.

From [PHP Manual: String Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), someone posted this which I find rather interesting. Notice how the space plays a part in the output.

**Excerpt:**
If you attempt to add numbers with a concatenation operator, your result will be the result of those numbers as strings.

```
<?php

echo "thr"."ee";           //prints the string "three"
echo "twe" . "lve";        //prints the string "twelve"
echo 1 . 2;                //prints the string "12"
echo 1.2;                  //prints the number 1.2
echo 1+2;                  //prints the number 3

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit of historical context.

- The PHP language started out as a set of Perl scripts.
- As such, PHP gets most of it's syntax from Perl.
- Perl, and by extension PHP, has untyped variables.

  ```
       "5"  ==   5
  "5" + 5   ==  10
  "5" . 5   ==  55
  ```
- To be able to tell the difference between addition and concatenation, they had to be two different operators.
- Perl copied the method access operator from C `->`.
- This was **before** many of the *more modern* programming languages started to use `.` for method access.
- Concatenation is one of the more common operations, and should use fewer characters. According to Huffman coding.
- `.` was one of the few characters available for this use. The only other one that would make sense to use is `~`, which is probably why that is now the Perl 6 concatenation operator.

Comment: Not sure where you've got Perl Home Page from, but in 12 yrs of PHP development, I've never heard it called this: "Personal Home Page Tools" maybe

Comment: Oh and it currently stands for "PHP Hypertext Preprocessor"

Comment: Grr at "untyped variables". That's an oversimplification.

Comment: Perl Home Page Tools is right. In the german version of the wikipedia article it is mentioned right in the first sentence: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Comment: I'm sure that I read that it was called Perl Home Page, sometime **before** it was released. That could just my mind playing tricks on me though. At any rate, I removed that item from the list, because this post seemed better without it.

Answer (score 2):

`+` should always be defined as a commutative operation (i.e., A+B = B+A). In the case of string concatenation, this is not the case ("foo" + "bar" != "bar" + "foo"). As such, `+` is not a good operator to use for the concatenation operation. Whether or not the language authors had this in mind when they used `.` instead (which is close to the multiplication operator, for which commutativity need not hold) remains to be seen, but it was a good decision nonetheless.

Comment: Even in math, addition is not always commutative; e.g. not for ordinal numbers.

Comment: @Pavel: huh?  I've never heard of anyone *trying* to add ordinals.  How does First + Second even compute?  Is the answer Third?  If so, why wouldn't Second + First also equal Third?

Answer (score 2):

While this isn't the historical reason it maybe show you why it is good to have a separate operator for addition and concatenation in the case of PHP.

The reason is what we see in JavaScript. We use the `+` character for concatenation and addition too. In PHP we have a separate operator for the two which is important for dynamically typed languages where implicit type conversion also present.

### In PHP

```php
echo  5  + 1; //6
echo  5  . 1; //51
echo "5" + 1; //6
echo "5" . 1; //51
```

This isn't surprising for anyone because we always explicitly stated whether we want to add or concatenate the two variable. Or in other words if we think about them as numbers or as strings.

### In JavaScript

```js
console.log( 5  +  1);  //6
console.log("5" +  1);  //51
console.log( 5  + "1"); //51
console.log("5" + "1"); //51
```

Without the knowledge of how implicit type conversions happen under the hood, in many cases (especially if they are complex) surprising results can happen, because we don't know what will be the outcome, because it isn't explicitly stated.

### In Python

Python also uses the `+` operator for concatenation and for addition too, but it doesn't let implicit type conversion to happen. You have to explicitly mark the type conversion.

```python
print  5  + 1 //6
print "5" + 1 //TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

We have to do type conversion to make it work: `a + int(b)`

### All in all

If we think about it, we can see that almost the same thing happens in PHP what we see in Python but instead of explicitly marking the type conversion, we mark with the operator that how we see the variables in terms of types.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is so you can concatenate numbers with strings?

```
$i=100;
$str="hello";
$str2 = $str.$i
```

Since you don't declare variable types, with a + it could give a result of 100 instead of "hello100."