# PHP string operations

Tags: php, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is the php string concatenation operator a dot (.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266799/why-is-the-php-string-concatenation-operator-a-dot)

I've always wondered -

Why does PHP use the . operator to concat strings instead of the + sign?

Is this some sort of way to improve script-evaluation performance?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because otherwise, what would happen in this case?

```
$str = "4";
$num = 2;

$result = $str + $num;
```

What if you wanted the result to be "42"?

**Clarification**

The above answers the question "why is there an operator `.` in addition to the operator `+`?". If the intended question was "why does operator `+` not perform string concatenation?" (with the understanding that the would need to be another operator to take over the current behavior `+`), then I 'll be happy to remove my answer in favor of a more relevant one.

Comment: Will the gentleman who downvoted please provide an explanation?

Comment: This is not the reason PHP uses `.` for string concatenation. There are languages that use `+` for string concatenation and `"4"+2` yields `"42"`.

Comment: @Gumbo: Sure. But then you would need another operator to enable `"4" + 2 == 6`, so it's chicken-and-egg.

Comment: @Jon: That depends on the implicit type conversion policy. In JavaScript, for example, the implicit type conversion is not to convert to string only if both operands are not numbers: `4 + 2 === 6`, `"4" + 2 === "42"`, `4 + "2" === "42"`, and `Number("4") + 2 === 6`.

Comment: @Gumbo: That doesn't address the issue. You would still need some operator `@` so that `"4" @ "2" == 6`.

Comment: @Jon: No, why would you? PHP has a weak typing system and it uses implicit type conversion before applying an operation with incompatible operand types. In languages with strong typing you would need an explicit type conversion.

Comment: @Gumbo: I didn't phrase that clearly. I mean that you 'd need an operator `@` in a world where `"4" + "2" == "42"`; clearly there has to be *some* way of indicating which operation you want to perform.

Comment: @Jon: The [operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) depends on the type of its operands.

Comment: @Gumbo: Please don't make this needlessly hard :) Yes, technically you would not need an *operator* in the sense that you could provide an explicit type conversion or cast and get the job done. But the designers of a language which forced you to do what would probably die of shame.

Answer (score 1):

After deciding that it (PHP) would do lots of autoboxing there was pretty much no other choice then to use 2 different operators for "adding" and "concating".

"+" for adding is obvious and @Gumbo explained why "." was chosen.

```
var_dump("12ab" + "34cd"); // 46
var_dump("12ab" . "34cd"); // "12ab34cd"
```

so you need to tell the language that you want it to do because it can do both :)

---

Other languages don't have that problem because they don't allow the implicit conversion from a string to an integer.

So if you write `"4" + 2` the language would tell you that it can't to that and you'd need to write: `intval("4") + 2` and it knows what to do.

### Also see here

[`why-is-the-php-string-concatenation-operator-a-dot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266799/why-is-the-php-string-concatenation-operator-a-dot)

Answer (score 0):

Because [Perl used the `.` for string concatenation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators) and PHP was highly influenced by Perl’s syntax.