# Concatenation operator in PHP

Tags: php, concatenation

During a conference that I attended some time ago, a .NET programmer that was a speaker there asked a question:

"Why is the concatenation operator in PHP different from the other languages?"

More exactly, why is it a dot instead of a plus?

At that time, nobody present knew the answer. Today, while playing with JavaScript I think that I found one reason. I'm curios if this is indeed the main reason why it's a dot instead of a plus.

I'll use JavaScript for the example:

```
var foo = 7;
var bar = 3;
console.log(foo+bar);
```

In this case, both variable's type is integer so the plus will behave the same way as it does in math, calculating the sum. The result will be 10.

Next scenario:

```
var foo = 7;
var bar = "3";
console.log(foo+bar);
```

In this case "foo" is an integer and "bar" is a string. The result would be 73.

I guess that a dot was used instead of a plus to kill some ambiguity regarding this particular case.

Just before posting this question I noticed a similar question on SO that have a similar answer to what I discovered today.

This is the link to the question: [Why is the php string concatenation operator a dot (.)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266799/why-is-the-php-string-concatenation-operator-a-dot)

Are there any more reasons besides this? Thank you for your time and please let me know if I need to edit my question before downrating. :)

Comment: People need to stop asking "Why?" of PHP. PHP does PHP things PHP's way for PHP's sake.

Comment: philosophy overflow is that way >>>>

Comment: actually, using same operator for concatenation and addition is usually considered a **design mistake** in programming languages.

Comment: It's a design mistake in languages that make the design mistake of not being able to tell between numbers and text.

Comment: It is not a language design mistake.

Comment: `(1 + 3) + 'a'` and `1 + (3 + 'a')`  ... should these be equal or not, and **why**? And then how about, if you hve `1 + 'a' + 3` and `1 + 3 + 'a'`?

Comment: Both PHP and Javascript perfectly know how to tell between a number and a string, they just choose to let the users be lazy and try to make sensible assumptions. This is quite practical but requires a bit of discipline, true... The fact that PHP allows you to increment an array bothers me much more :)

Comment: I love these questions. These and the ones where people hold shift and smash their keyboard then ask why the output is what it is. `<?php $a=0; echo $a++ ++$a-2++*&&<<$a++;` POR QUE???

Comment: @tereško, yes, those wild type castings break associativity - this is shocking for my math background

Comment: When thinking about why PHP is designed the way it is, I generally assume that alcohol played a major role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PHP was originally developed in Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#History), from which it borrowed a lot of its syntax. This includes the use of `.` as a string concatenation operator, and the prefix `$` for variable names.

Comment: Check out "Design Errors". http://www.crockford.com/javascript/javascript.html