# HTML/PHP GET only retrieves numeric input

Tags: php, html, get, alphanumeric

I'm using XAMPP and have a php site that should print out the input passed by GET. The URL looks like `http://127.0.0.1/profile.php?id=643bqmxf9rj62`.

In the php file I have this code:

```
$accId= $_GET['id'];
echo "accId = " + $accIdd;
```

What gets printed is simply
`643`, without the `accId =`. Anything after the first character that isn't a digit gets cut off.

When I pass `bqmxf9rj62` in the URL without numbers in front, my script prints `0`.

I have made websites before but I can't figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the wrong operator for concatenation. In php, the concatenation operator is a period/dot: `.`

So your code should be:

```
echo "accId = " . $accIdd;
```

A plus sign `+` is the concatenation operator in JavaScript.

Using the `+` here means you're actually adding things together, not concatenating, so PHP is thinking `blah + 643etc = 643`.

Comment: Wow, it's really been a while since I last touched PHP. This is hilarious considering how angry it made me by now. Thank you. Accepting your answer as soon as the site lets me.

Comment: Here are some more details about why PHP designers chose to use the dot operator instead of plus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866098/why-a-full-stop-and-not-a-plus-symbol-for-string-concatenation-in-php