# INSERT INTO not working for first time and later works

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

```
    <?php
include "../au.php";

$towhom = $_POST['towhom'];
$content = $_POST['content'];

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/KolKata');
$xyz = date(DATE_RFC2822);

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'local', 'local');
mysql_select_db('chat', $conn);

$q = "INSERT INTO $na (one, two, five, content, ip)
VALUES ('$na', 'sent', '$xyz', '$content', '$ip');";
$w = "INSERT INTO $towhom (one, two, five, content, ip) VALUES ( '$na', 'recieved', '$xyz', '$content', '$ip' );";

if (mysql_query($q)){
echo "<br>&nbsp; Message sent to '".$towhom."'";
} else {
    echo "<br>&nbsp; Failed 1";
}
if (mysql_query($w)){
echo "<br>&nbsp; Message sent to '".$towhom."'";
} else {
    echo "<br>&nbsp; Failed 2";
}
?>
```

DESCRIPTION : This is messaging script. $towhom and $content are taken from form. $xyz is defined. $na and $ip are defined in au.php file.

PROBLEM : $q is not successful while $w works.

Comment: Could you please add change to `mysql_query($q) or die(mysql_error())` so you could post the error you are getting ?

Comment: `mysql_connect()` extension is deprecated better use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0):

Without any other information, my guess is that the string contained in `$towhom` does not refer to a valid table. If I'm sending a message to "some_user", the query stored in `$w` would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO some_user (...) VALUES (...)
```

Do you mean to have a unique table for every user?  And if so, are you sure that such tables exist?  Some error output would be very useful.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Remove unwanted semicolons from your queries

```
$q = "INSERT INTO $na (one, two, five, content, ip)
VALUES ('$na', 'sent', '$xyz', '$content', '$ip')";
$w = "INSERT INTO $towhom (one, two, five, content, ip) VALUES ( '$na', 'recieved', '$xyz', '$content', '$ip' )";
```

Then

> PROBLEM : $q is not successful while $w works.

If a query is not successful means there could be lot of reasons. You should check it using `mysql_query($q)` or `die(mysql_error())`

Comment: Down voters should explain why..? otherwise why do you down vote

Answer (score -1):

Think multiline strings are causing issues... Not sure though...

Try,

```
$q = "INSERT INTO $na (one, two, five, content, ip) " +
     "VALUES ('$na', 'sent', '$xyz', '$content', '$ip')";
```

Comment: How come You are giving such an answer ? In php plus sign does not concatenate strings Right?

Comment: I suppose, . (dot). Correct if wrong. Sorry! Was thinking from Java perspective.!

Comment: You need to learn the way php codes are read. See why a dot and why not + symbol for string concatenation http://stackoverflow.com/q/1866098/3577946

Comment: Your answer doesnt make any sense to the op.