# MySQL Query Returns 0 When Running Multirowed Response Query

Tags: php, concatenation

When I run the following code In PHP

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "dbpass", "db");

function csvfromarray($array) {
    $result = $array[0]+","+$array[1];
    return $result;
}

$query = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM dbtable");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$data = array();
$i = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $data[$i] = $row['last'];
        $i++;
}
$csv = csvfromarray($data);
echo $csv;
mysqli_close();
```

I end up getting an echoed response of "0" when I should be returning "lname1,lname2".

Comment: `+` is math. `.` is for concatenation. e.g. `$array[0] . "," . $array[1];` or you could use `implode` if all of `$array` should be joined by commas.

Comment: Thanks, Looks like I have been coding in Java way to much lately.

Comment: Yea, you also should look at the PHP functions for building a CSV. If your data ever has a `,` in it you'll end up with a malformed CSV with this approach. You also can just use `[]` you don't need the `$i`, PHP will auto increment that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why a full stop, "." and not a plus symbol, "+", for string concatenation in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866098/why-a-full-stop-and-not-a-plus-symbol-for-string-concatenation-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of chris85's stuff is correct...

Here's a tidy up:

```
$query=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT `last` FROM dbtable");
$data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $data[]=$row['last'];    // push into array
}
echo implode(',',$data);   // echo comma-separated values
mysqli_close();
```