# How to get permalink to a specific WooCommerce endpoint?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, permalinks

Hi I am looking how to get a permalink to a woocommerce my account page endpoint. For example edit-address or orders.

I tried this which I know can't possibly be right, it also appends a 0 onto the end of the link.

```
get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') )+"orders";
```

Comment: PHP concatenation is dot symbol not plus symbol. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1866194/1593365. Your code seems right only.

Comment: perfect, thank you!

Comment: Learn PHP syntax then this kind of issues will be lesser or nil.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Replace your code with this

```
get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ) . "orders";
```

PHP concatenation is dot symbol not plus symbol. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1866194/1593365. Your code seems right only

Answer (score 7):

You should use [wc_get_endpoint_url()](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_endpoint_url.html), it will get endpoint value you set in Woocommerce settings so if you change it one day, your URLs will be updated.

```
wc_get_endpoint_url('orders', '', get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id')))
```

Available endpoints are :

- view-order
- edit-account
- dashboard
- orders
- downloads
- edit-address
- payment-methods
- customer-logout

Comment: You should replace `get_permalink(get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id'))` with `wc_get_page_permalink('myaccount')`